# same keyword in different cases for SEO

Tags: seo, keywords, meta-keywords

Is it good for **SEO** to add same word in indifferent case to match all possible search key word. Like

```
<meta name="keywords" content="shoe, Shoe, SHOE ">
```

Is it considered good or duplicate?

Comment: No. Search engines understand these things extremely well. You should not be trying to manage keywords so tightly. As well, the keyword meta-tag is effectively useless.

Comment: so you mean I should use any single case.right? then which case is good practice?@closetnoc

Comment: To begin, the keyword meta tag should not be used. Stop. Do not bother. You are wasting your time. Otherwise, in all your other tags such as title tag, description meta-tag, header tags, and so forth, use what makes sense "once" or twice as it fits. Be conversational and compelling. Make these tags for humans (sentences/headlines), but do try and put any important keyword in order from left to right and as close to the beginning of your sentence as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the meta-keyword tag, or at the very least, ditch the same repeating words regardless of whether the letters are upper or lower case. Google doesn't pay much attention to meta-keywords and I believe Bing will use them against you if they are used the way you do. You're trying to rank for a keyword in an artificial way.

The only meta tag you should use to add the relevant keyword only once to is the meta description tag. For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Find out how large black shoes are made">
```

And if you really need to rank for shoes, maybe find another word close enough to it you can use in your description. For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="We sell shoes, and other footwear in our large online store">
```

Comment: so i can remove meta-keyword without any tension (if i use a good description).?

Comment: That would be a perfect move.